# Wanting DIV background to stretch outside parent DIV in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items, like a menu, where the current item has a background image that is kind of like a big pointer to the right. This background image pointer thing should escape the bounding box of the div it's contained within. Here is a screenshot of how it appears in Chrome and FF, which is as i expected it to appear:

[image]

I've set up a jsfiddle with the code, minus the background image thing as I can't be bothered uploading it anywhere. But I've set the background colour so you can see what I'm referring to

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/V8TNm/

So in Chrome and FF, the yellow background of the active item will stretch past the grey gradient box. But in IE9, it's cut off.

Any ideas why, and what an easy fix may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add position:relative.

```
#nav_mod_list div.current {
position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8TNm/3/

Comment: So, does this mean we still have to worry about `hasLayout` on IE9?

Comment: @Connor, it's not hasLayout, [unless the browser is running of some compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405844(v=vs.85).aspx). I feel relieved!

Answer (score 0):

The selector `#nav_mod_list div.current` has a width of `210px` as well as padding and margin where as the container is `200px`.  Change the 210 to 200 and remove the margin and padding.

**Edit:**

You could also just remove `width` property altogether.  That way it will simply extend the width of the container.